# Dynamica Database - array - pass valueS from page 1 to pag 2 with PHP/MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have  dynamic database working very well.

I have log in system working very well.

There are those "welcome user" links.

"user" is a link to everything user has in DB.
When a user wants to change stuff, just click on "user".
You get the form ChangeStuff.php

Amongst other good stuff, I have this

```
<form action="IamStuck.php">

<li> Property ID: <?php  print  $row['P_ID'] ?>  <?php $P_ID =  $row['P_ID']; $_SESSION['P_ID']  = $P_ID  ?><input name="edit" type="submit" value="edit" /><br /><br />
&ensp;&ensp;  Address: <?php print $row['address']?>,   <?php print $row['city'] ; ?> 
</li>  
</form>
```

Which basically produces something like this:

**Edit Listings**

Would you like to update your listing?

- Property ID: 14 **(submit button goes here)**

  Address: 1845 Oak Park Blvd, Pleasanton Hill
- Property ID: 16 **(submit button goes here)**

  Address: 3111 Adeline Ave, Emeryville

Then on the IamStuck.php, I have a full form (html+php) that pulls all the info on DB and allows user to update the info (query is fine and working very well):

```
    <?php  session_start();
.....
        $P_ID = $_SESSION ['P_ID'];
        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){//if the submit button is clicked
        $day = $_POST['day'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        etc
        etc.


    $update = "UPDATE property 
                    SET day='$day', city='$city', state='$state', address='$address', price = $price, sq_ft = $sq_ft, lot_sq_ft = $lot_sq_ft,zip_code = $zip_code, bedroom = $bedroom, bathroom = $bathroom, partial_bath = $partial_bath, sunday_info = '$sunday_info',
                    web = '$web', broker_info='$broker_info', map_info='$map_info', youtube = '$youtube'

                     WHERE P_ID = ".$P_ID;
        $db->query($update) or die("Cannot update");//update or error
```

The problem is to get the right P_ID from ChangeStuff.php

I tried this with anchor link and post/get and it worked wonderfully, except that the P_ID would go in the URL and you could just change the id and change someone's else DB info :O

No good.

Came back to session. 
It works very well as long as you want to change the last value of the array :)

If you want to change the property 14 (as seen in the example) you jut can't :( Pulls only last address (which is still your info in DB - but not the one supposed to be updated.

No good.

Is there any one out in there  in blue planet who could give some ideas?

Full disclosure: I am new to this stuff of PHP, MYSQL, Javascript CSS all this wonderful stuff that I have been learning in the last several months :/

Thank you for your time.

PS. As you may have figured out, the array is dynamic, will change from person to person and even from the same person today to next month.

**EDIT**

Based on one of the comment below @Just Wood
I came back to my original Post/Get method. 
changeStuff.php is like this:

```
<form action="IamLessStuck.php" method="post">

    <li> <a href="IamLessStuck.php?P_ID=<?php echo $row['P_ID']; ?>">Property ID: <?php  print  $row['P_ID'] ?> </a><br /><br />
    &ensp;&ensp;  Address: <?php print $row['address']?>,   <?php print $row['city'] ; ?> 
    </li>  
    </form>
```

IamLessStuck.php
 is like this (just WHERE changed):

```
$update = "UPDATE property 
            SET day='$day', city='$city', state='$state', address='$address', price = $price, sq_ft = $sq_ft, lot_sq_ft = $lot_sq_ft,zip_code = $zip_code, bedroom = $bedroom, bathroom = $bathroom, partial_bath = $partial_bath, sunday_info = '$sunday_info',
            web = '$web', broker_info='$broker_info', map_info='$map_info', youtube = '$youtube'

             WHERE P_ID = ".$P_ID." and 
                           username =  '".(htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username']))."'";

$db->query($update) or die("Cannot update");//update or error
```

Thank you. It works. 
I also changed the code/query where query SELECT *.... to get all values before the edit takes place and added the same  WHERE clause (id=$_post id and user = session[user]). 
Now one can only see and change his/her only stuff. 
Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to execute your queries? None of that looks [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/). If your database layer supports placeholder values, please, use those.

Comment: You could pass it in a session(). You also could just re-authenticate the user and make sure they are updating something they have rights to before making the change.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting the P_ID in the URL. All you would need to do is verify that the user CAN access that entry BEFORE making any changes.

Comment: Try adding the P_ID as a hidden form field on your ChangeSTuff.php page and reference that on the IamStuck.php page for use in your query. ALWAYS SANITIZE user input before building your query.

Comment: I did a minor update on Question adding how I get the values (I am not sure if this is your question). I am new to programming and once this is working I will go back to do necessary changes for security. It's hard to learn Computer in a few months :/

Comment: Also, I am using session now. I have looked over the internet, and there are tutorials for static arrays passed over session. Not about arrays that are created dynamically and change from user to user. @Justin Wood. How can I do that? Thank you so much for all the comments.

Comment: Just check to see if that user owns that object in the database before allowing them the view that entry, this will be a database query. I don't know what that query will be on account of I don't know what your database looks like. If they do not own the entry, redirect them elsewhere. You will want to redirect to the same page even if the entry is not in the database.

Comment: @Justin Wood I updated question with new WHERE clause. Thank you. I changed both the UPDATE and the SELECT (to pull the form with data) and added the WHERE id=&id and user = session[user]. Now all is beatiful. Thank you.

Comment: So this is working for you? Do you mind if I add my comments as an answer so you can mark it as correct? As a side note, I do not agree with putting the P_ID into the session, as it has nothing to do with a session. That is a single request needing that information.

Comment: go ahead. you helped in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem at all with putting the `P_ID` in the URL. All you will need to do is check to make sure that that user has access to that entry before allowing them to edit/view it.

Just do a SQL query to check for that.

As a side note, as mentioned in my comments, I do not agree with putting the `P_ID` in with the rest of the session information. The `P_ID` has to do with a single request, not the entire session.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the WHERE clause as you can see in the edited question - see EDIT.